# Esri enterprise GDB features showing as non-spatial table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

Why are Esri's Enterprise geodatabase 10.4.1 (in MS SQL Server 2012) feature classes showing as  non-spatial table/spatial type is 'no Geometry' in QGIS?

The storage properties of the feature class in ArcCatalog shows as ST-Geometry spatial type(SRID 300001).

Comment: I think ESRI store the geometry in a non standard format that qgis can't read...

Comment: It's been years and years since the default geometry type wasn't the Microsoft native `geometry` and I believe the Esri geometry implementation has been deprecated and retired, so you'll need to [Edit] the question to specify the exact SQL Server release you are using, and the version of your Enterprise geodatabase.

Comment: hi Vince, i am using MS Sql Server 2012 and enterprise geodatabase 10.4.1